# how to take iphone screenshot programmatically on macbook?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, macos

xcode has the ability to take screenshot on iPhone when the phone is connected (Organizer->Screenshots->New Screenshot). My question is how can I implement the same thing.

I searched on Google but I can only find
- How to write an iPhone app to take screenshot on iPhone (but I want a MacBook app to take screenshot on iPhone).
- How to take screenshot of my MacBook (but I want to take screenshot on iPhone).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7311332/795339) might be of interest.

Comment: @esker: Yes, that is exact what I want and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible. Xcode is most likely using private APIs to trigger taking a screenshot.

Comment: *you don't think* is not strong enough to make it an answer.