# iPhone screenshot from Windows command line

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, macos, instruments

I want to get the screenshot from my iPhone connected to Windows laptop though USB. Is there a command line tool (like adb in Android) to achieve this?

This is what I want to achieve step-by-step:

1. Connect an iPhone to Windows machine
2. Run a command to get the screenshot from the attached iPhone (USB)
3. Save the screenshot on the windows machine

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311332/programatically-get-ios-device-screenshot-from-the-connected-mac-computer

Comment: The tool mentioned here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311332/programatically-get-ios-device-screenshot-from-the-connected-mac-computer) is for MAC. Is there anything similar for Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [idevicescreenshot](http://docs.quamotion.mobi/docs/imobiledevice/tools/idevicescreenshot/) to take a screenshot of an iOS device.

We have compiled a Windows version of idevicescreenshot. You can download it at http://docs.quamotion.mobi/docs/download/ (look for the *libimobiledevice* download link at the bottom of the table).

As pointed out by others, you need to mount the Developer Disk on your iPhone for the idevicescreenshot to work. We've got instructions on how to do that here: http://docs.quamotion.mobi/docs/imobiledevice/howto/howto-mount-apple-developer-disk/

If you've got any questions, feel free to ask them here at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a command-line option, but you can get a screenshot over USB with Xcode (on Mac) by opening Xcode, going to (from the status bar at the top) Window -> Organizer -> Devices tab, choosing Screenshots underneath your device on the left, and in the bottom right there's a New Screenshot button. You can then click Export at the bottom to save the image somewhere...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, jjv360. My requirement is to do that automatically/programatically through code on web server and the screenshot would be displayed remotely on clients.

Comment: It may be possible with UIAutomation (which I know nothing about)... Here's a link to something someone made to automatically take screenshots, not sure if it will help you: https://github.com/toursprung/iOS-Screenshot-Automator

Comment: Instruments works only inside the app. It doesn't work for screens outside your app

Answer (score 0):

Please try Reflector. It will serve your problem. It is free for 30 day.

http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/

Comment: I know there are tools like Reflector and iTools which can Mirror the iPhone screen on desktop. I want to know how they are able to do this. I want to do this programatically or using some command.

Comment: @AnujKapoor Most of these apps just run an AirPlay server, then have you mirror your device to it.

Answer (score 0):

If the device has the Development disk image mounted, you can access the screenshotr service through lockdownd to create screenshots. I've created a project using libimobiledevice to demonstrate this at [ryanp-me/ios-screenshot](https://github.com/ryanp-me/ios-screenshot/blob/master/iOS%20Screenshot/ISDevice.cpp). You could also take a look at [ideviceinfo](https://github.com/mcolyer/libiphone/blob/master/tools/ideviceinfo.c), which does the same thing in less lines of code, but without converting the image to a PNG.

If you need to be able to take screenshots without the device being previously setup as a developer device, you might be able to use [ideviceimagemounter](https://github.com/mcolyer/libiphone/blob/master/tools/ideviceimagemounter.c) to mount the developer disk image before hand.